# Using SQL Aliases in following fields that perform arithmetic

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, count, left-join

I have this MySQL query which counts clicks and submissions. I then want to work out the ratio of how many clicks became a submission. The following query gives me exactly what I want:

```
SELECT
clicks.review_id,
COUNT(clicks.id) as clicks,
COUNT(submissions.id) as submissions,
ROUND((((COUNT(submissions.id))/(COUNT(clicks.id)))*100),1) as rate,
submissions / clicks as other
FROM submissions
RIGHT JOIN clicks ON clicks.id = submissions.click_id
GROUP BY clicks.review_id
ORDER BY rate DESC
```

Result:

```
review_id, clicks, submissions, rate
5,429,314,73.2
etc
```

Is there a way I can use the aliases of  'clicks' and 'submissions' in the following line, instead of doing the count again? Something like:

```
ROUND(((submissions/clicks)*100),1) as rate,
```

Comment: No, but you can use a subquery so you don't have to type everything twice

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned you can use subquery, like:

```
SELECT
clicks,submissions,
ROUND(((submissions/clicks)*100),1) as rate
FROM(SELECT
clicks.review_id,
COUNT(clicks.id) as clicks,
COUNT(submissions.id) as submissions
FROM submissions
RIGHT JOIN clicks ON clicks.id = submissions.click_id
GROUP BY clicks.review_id
ORDER BY rate DESC) inr
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to reuse columns you are computing on the fly you'll need to produce a "table expression" where those new columns *live*. Then, the main query can use them directly.

For example:

```
select
  *,
  round(((submissions / clicks) * 100), 1) as rate,
  submissions / clicks as other
from (
  select
    c.review_id,
    count(c.id) as clicks,
    count(s.id) as submissions
  from submissions s
  right join clicks c on c.id = s.click_id
  group by c.review_id
) x
order by rate desc
```

You can see the computed columns `clicks` and `submissions` are produced by the inner "table expression" `x`, so the main query can access them.

Answer (score 0):

You can't reuse aliases defined in the `select` clause in the same clause - you need a subquery or common table expression, as demonstrated in other answers.

But overall, you could vastly simplify the logic of the query by rewriting it as follows:

```
select
    c.review_id,
    count(*) as clicks,
    count(s.id) as submissions,
    round(avg(s.id is not null) * 100, 1) as rate
from clicks c
left join submissions s on s.click_id = c.idd
group by c.review_id
order by rate desc
```

The query uses a `left join` to get all the clicks, and attempts to match the submission, whenever possible. `count(*)` gives you the number of clicks, while `count(s.id)` counts matched submissions only. Then, `avg()` comes handy to compute the ratio: the conversion rate actually is the average match ratio of the `left join`.